# Keep php generated page content, when opening it from another computer

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I can't figure out something.

Let's say you have a page with an html form. The form sends some information to a PHP script which uses some SQL and gathers information from MySQL database based on the user's input. It then redirects the user to another page, where he can see the output.

Now, I want the user to be able to open the link to the page with the output from another browser or even another computer and see the result without having to go through the form again. I know I could keep the user input in a PHP session variable, or a cookie, but that seems to work only in the current session(as it should). Now, my question is how to make it work if the output page is opened - lets say in another browser or on another computer? I assume it can be done with PHP but I have no idea how.

P.S.: If you think that the title or some of the information should be change, I'll be glad to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant when I wrote this question some time ago, was to be able to open content from a view, by typing : "www.mysite.com/foo" for example, when such page "foo.php" doesn't actually exist on the server side. Back then I had no idea how to do this. The answer to the question is as follows:

Views, such as foo.php don't really have any page behind them, they are a kind of partials - just a part of html. In that case, one needs something on the server side, which can rewrite urls to a controller on an index page, which opens the right view. In PHP this can be done very easily with a framework like Silex.

After that, when you write "www.mysite.com/foo", the controller automatically loads the "foo" view.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another table that stores all the responses to the form. Then give that row in the table a unique ID. When your user visits website.com/response.php?id={unique ID} show the appropriate responses.

Comment: Hmm... Yeah you may be right, but wouldn't it use too much memory? Lets say I have a table with 2000 rows, and the user can filter the results in 5 input fields for each column, four of which expect string values. Wouldn't this lead to an incredibly big response table?